# Excel - summation of 2 items in a column until a specific total

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I had the following Excel table:

| Type | No |
| --- | --- |
| OP | 2 |
| OP | 5 |
| LD | 7 |
| HL | 12 |
| OP | 3 |

Without using VBA, is it possible to summarize the above data as follow:

| Type | No |
| --- | --- |
| OP | 7 (2+5) |
| LD | 7 |
| ----- | ----- |
| Total | 14 |

OP+LD must be <=14, otherwise, stop.

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: I don't think there is a purely formula solution. There is an add-in called solver that tries to find a solution based on formulas (constraints). Beyond this, the constraint problem you are proposing can get complicated, hence a  whole field of study called operations research.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could really suggest is an ugly formula in a helper column. Please see the example below. Maybe it will give you some thoughts.

[image]